# what exactly happens if I set two parameter in for statement?

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, iterable-unpacking

```
lst = ['first', 'second']

for q,w in lst:
 print(q)
 print(w)
```

If I set my code like this, the result is an error.
But if I do this way:

```
lst = [['first', 'second']]

  for q,w in lst:
    print(q)
    print(w)
```

The output is #first #second .

I don't understand the mechanism for this.. can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you mean unpacking items from the list inside a `for` loop?

Comment: try `lst = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,"got it?"]]`

Comment: when you search for `python for loop tuple unpacking site:stackoverflow.com` you find plenty of other questions circling around the same topic - I selected one as dupe for you.

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop is a form of an assignment statement. Each iteration assigns a new value to the target, and just like in a simple assignment statement, the target can be a sequence for tuple unpacking.

Your loop is equivalent to

```
for t in lst:
    q, w = t
    print(q)
    print(w)
```

The key difference is that in your first code, `t` is a string with more than 2 characters, so the unpacking fails. In the second code, `t` is a list with exactly 2 elements, so the unpacking succeeds.